# Regex replace new lines in between start and end

Tags: java, javascript, php, python, regex

I have a string that includes new lines.  Between the lines that are `"""`, I want to add semicolons just before `\n`.

Example input string:

```
print and not affected
"""
This is my game
dead or alive
ALIVE!
"""
```

Example output string:

```
print and not affected
"""
This is my game;
dead or alive;
ALIVE!;
"""
```

Currently, I have a regex that looks something like:

```
"""([^\n]*\n)*"""
```

Why isn't it working?

By the way, PHP, Java, JavaScript, or Python code examples work for me.

Comment: Ah, you mean prefix not replace.

Comment: @Icy is the solution for only the above example would be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PHP**

Try the below regex and replace the matched newline characters with `;\n`,

```
(?s)(?:(?<=^)(?:(?!""").)*|(?:(?!""").)*(?=$)|"""\n)(*SKIP)(*F)|\n
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rG2hB9/2)

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. I am looking forward to analyzing this. =)

Answer (score 3):

If you mean, add semicolon to the end of each line within triple quotes, you can't do it with one regexp - regexps are not powerful enough for that. This JavaScript should do the trick:

```
var a = 'print and not affected\n"""\nThis is my game\ndead or alive\nALIVE!\n"""';
a.replace(/("""\n?)([^]*?)(""")/mg, function(_, o, m, c) {
  return o + m.replace(/\n/g, ";\n") + c;
});
// =>
// print and not affected
// """
// This is my game;
// dead or alive;
// ALIVE!;
// """
```

Comment: This is sleek =), I love the compactness of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell it to replace the `\n` between the `"""` in one line by using the following regex.

`/(^.+\n.+)?([^\"].+)\n/`

Examples

PHP

```
$txt = 'print and not affected\n"""\nThis is my game\ndead or alive\nALIVE!\n"""\n';
$output = preg_replace("/(^.+\n.+)?([^\"].+)\n/", "$1$2;\n", $txt);
echo $output;
```

Javascript

```
var txt = 'print and not affected\n"""\nThis is my game\ndead or alive\nALIVE!\n"""\n';
var output = txt.replace(/(^.+\n.+)?([^\"].+)\n/g, "$1$2;\n");
console.log(output);
```

In both cases this will output:

```
print and not affected
"""
This is my game;
dead or alive;
ALIVE!;
"""
```

Basically we match the first line and the first set of `"""` and put it back untouched with `$1`. Then we find any line that does not have `"` next to the `\n`. We put back those lines with `$2`, but because we did not include `\n` between our `()` and it is not next to `"` it is the only thing subject to our change `;\n`. This not a precise explanation but the best I can do when I am tired.

[Link to example on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/rG2hB9/3)

Comment: @AvinashRaj. Actual it is, but the link that you gave used the m flag which is incorrect and does not match the example I gave. See [http://regex101.com/r/rG2hB9/3](http://regex101.com/r/rG2hB9/3)

Comment: Genius, this is awesome. Exactly what I asked for, but didn't work because when it had more than one line before the """, then it messed up some how. Other than that, sweet.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in one regex.  Anyway, what I've written is not an elegant solution, but it works (JavaScript):

```
var str = //your original string

str = str.split(/\n/); //split it by new line into an array

var opened = false;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === '"""') {
        opened = ~opened; //toggle opened
        continue;
    }

    if (opened) {
        str[i] = str[i] + ";"; //add semicolon    
    }
}

str = str.join('\n');  //rejoin string
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mtyrv2v3/2/)

Comment: I like the way you think. +1 for finding a variant solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's more than one way to do the regexes, but universally, you need at least two for this operation.

The two regexes I'll use are:

1. `"""[\s\S]*?"""`.  This will match everything in the `"""`'s until the earliest terminator quotes.
2. `[^"]\n`.  This makes sure that your newline isn't preceeded by a quote to prevent the semicolon from appearing right after the opening `"""`'s.

Example:

```
var text = 'print and not affected\n' 
    + '"""\n' 
    + 'This is my game\n' 
    + 'dead or alive\n' 
    + 'ALIVE!\n' 
    + '"""\n';



var result = text.replace(/"""[\s\S]*?"""/g, function(match) {

    return match.replace(/[^"]\n/g, function(match) {

        return match[0] + ";\n";

    });

});
```